# Testing if a point lies within a labeled object with scipys ndi.label()

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-image, ndimage

[image: Labelled Image]

Above is an image that has been put through `ndi.label()`and displayed with matplotlib with each coloured region representing a different feature. Plotted on top of the image are red points that represent a pair of coordinates each. All coordinates are stored and ndi.label returns the number of features. Does skimage, scipy or ndimage have a function that will test if a given set of coordinates lies within a labelled feature?

Initially I intended to use the binding box (left, right, top, bottom) of each feature but due to the regions not all being quadrilateral this won't work.

code to generate the image:

```
image = io.import("image path")
labelledImage, featureNumber = ndi.label(image)
plt.imshow(labelledImage)

for i in range(len(list))
    y, x = list[i]
    plt.scatter(y,x, c='r', s=40)
```

Comment: How are coordinates stored? Is the labeled image a numpy array? Can you show the code that generates it?

Comment: @user13044086 The image is a numpy array, this is default through skimage. Coordinates are stored in a list location such that: for i pairs of coordinates:  x, y = list[i]

Comment: Can you just check that all elements of labelledImage are the same for the given coordinates? Like so: `[labelledImage[y, x] for x, y in list]` And then check ell elements are the same

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ndi.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html) to find the value at a particular coordinate (or group of coordinates) in an image:

```py
labels_at_coords = ndi.map_coordinates(
        labelledImage, np.transpose(list), order=0
        )
```

Notes:

- the coordinates array needs to be of shape `(ndim, npoints)`, instead of the sometimes more intuitive `(npoints, ndim)`, hence the transpose.
- ideally, it would be best to rename your points list to something like `points_list`, so that you don't overwrite the Python built-in function `list`.

Comment: I would add to your answer something like `len(np.unique(labels_at_coords)) == 1`, to actually evaluate whether the "given set of coordinates lies within" *the same* "labelled feature", or `len(np.unique(labels_at_coords)) == 1 & np.unique(labels_at_coords) == label` to evaluate whether the "given set of coordinates lies within a" *specific* "labelled feature" *with label* `label`. One of these is ultimately the question asked.